# How i can make transmission line from inducor and capacitor

Tags: capacitor, inductor

The questions are:

1. How can i make an inductor using transmission line?
2. How can i make a capacitor using transmission line?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Electrical Engineering StackExchange. Please edit your question and provide further detail and context, in order to help other users help you.

Comment: Your question and your title seem to be asking two opposite questions.

Comment: Yes i have asked two questions in one title

Comment: @MimiMouse Is this related to [Richard's transformations](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/723/handouts/Richards%20Tranformation%20.pdf) and [Commensurate line circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurate_line_circuit)? - Your question is **very** bony, some meat to the bones would make this question proper.

Comment: It's a conceptual question for job interview can any one help me to find the answer

Comment: Take a transmission line that's significantly shorter than 1/4 wavelength at the highest frequency of interest.  Connect the near ends to your circuit (this works best if one end is grounded).  Short the far end -- it's an inductor.  Now open the far end -- it's a capacitor.  Now go study so you can answer the follow-on question, which is "why?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short circuit terminated transmission line will look like an inductor or a capacitor at certain lengths when driven at the appropriate frequency: -

[image]

[This website](https://www.daenotes.com/electronics/communication-system/short-circuited-transmission-line) where I took the image also shows the result if the transmission line is open circuit [here](https://www.daenotes.com/electronics/communication-system/open-circuited-transmission-line).

My answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/318058/what-is-the-difference-between-characteristic-impedance-and-input-impedance-in-t) gives a little more insight to the math.