# Calculating lengths of single-stub transmission line when all 3 characteristic impedances differ

Tags: transmission-line, impedance-matching, characteristic-impedance, tuning

Consider a transmission line circuit like the following but where \$Z_{o2}\$ was also unique (say \$Z_{o2}=7\,\Omega\$):

[image]

I know how I would find \$l_1\$ and \$l_2\$ using smith charts:

$$Re\left\{Y_n(z=-l_1)\right\}=\frac{Z_{o1}}{Z_o}=0.5\rightarrow l_1=\left(0.106\lambda,\,0.394\lambda\right)$$

$$Y(z=-l_1)=Y_n(z=-l_1)\cdot Y_{o1}$$

$$Y_n(z=-l_2)=\frac{-Im\left\{Y(z=-l_1)\right\}}{Y_{o2}}=0.161j\rightarrow l_2=(0.161\lambda,\,0.349\lambda)$$

but, since I would like to write a program for calculating this, I need to be able to solve this from the governing equations.

Starting on page 230 in [this book](https://ecedmans.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/lectures-ii.pdf), the author describes the equations used for matching a circuit where \$Z_o=Z_{o1}=Z_{o2}\$ but how would I solve this problem in the more general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally you could use this equation: -

[image]

So, the two t-lines will each present an impedance at the node where they join and that therefore becomes a parallel impedance that is then presented as the load on the output of the t-line coming from the left.

Formula Image from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/318058/what-is-the-difference-between-characteristic-impedance-and-input-impedance-in-t).

Comment: Thanks! Say I am comfortable calculating l1 and just want to use this eq to find l2; could you help get me started on that?

Comment: @Landon are we done here?