# Phase Constant of Transmission Lines when R, G, L and C values are unknown

Tags: transmission-line

> A lossless transmission line of length 0.57 m is connected to a vector network analyser. When terminated in a short circuit the input impedance was measured to be: Zin (s/c) = j45 Ω. When terminated in an open circuit the input impedance was measured to be: Zin (o/c) = - j125 Ω. From other measurements it is known that the length of the line is 3λ.
>
> Find the phase constant (β) of the transmission line in the other measurement.

The answer should be 33.1 rad/m but I am not sure how to get there. I would normally work out the propogation constant first using the R, G, L and C values and then deduce the phase constant from there, but the values aren't given in the question. Any explainations are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this might help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/318058/what-is-the-difference-between-characteristic-impedance-and-input-impedance-in-t/318063#318063)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this looks like a homework problem I will refrain from solving the question in its entirety, but I'll give a framework for the solution that you can apply to get a final answer.

You know first that multiplying the magnitudes of Zin(s/c) and Zin(o/c) gives you \$Z_0^2\$ as justified in the footnote<sup>1</sup>; this value is 5625 so you know that this is a 75-ohm line.

Next, given that the line length is approximately 3λ, we need to account for the fact that the actual s/c and o/c impedances aren't perfect shorts/opens. With the help of a smith chart (e.g. by trial and error), or by using the [mathematical statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_coefficient#Relation_to_load_impedance) relating the reflection coefficient seen at the input with the input impedance, you can find that the actual line length is *slightly* higher than 3λ (the Zin(s/c) and Zin(o/c) are satisfied for lengths just above 0, λ/2, λ, 3λ/2, ...).

After that, it's simple geometry and accounting for length - you have an electrical length in wavelengths, multiply by 2*pi to get length in radians, and divide by your physical length to get your phase constant.

<sup>1</sup>They are reciprocals of each other so their product is 1 when measured as *normalized* impedances, and the equation is simply scaled by multiplying both sides by Z_0.

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't a homework problem, I am just doing a past paper which the lecturer has released to prepare for my exam on friday but I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @asifkhan123 no problem, feel free to add a comment if you need any more assistance or clarity at any point.