# How can I intuitively understand input impedance?

Tags: transmission-line

Let's say we have a lossless transmission line with Zo impedance, terminated by a ZL =  R+jX load. The question I was asked is for what input impedance the voltage would be maximum or minimum.

What I understand so far is the voltage will be maximum when βl is equal to the phase angle of the reflection coefficient, and will be minimum when βl is equal to the phase angle of the reflection coefficient +/- π. But how can I connect this idea to the input impedance? would be maximum or minimum when the input impedance is 1/ZL or ZL?

Comment: ZL has units of impedance.  1/ZL has units of conductance.  So an impedance *cannot* be equal to 1/ZL.  Note that there are some intuitive candidates other than "equal to ZL", such as "complex conjugate of ZL" or "Zo*Zo/ZL" or "zero".  You also need to consider the length (in wavelengths) of the transmission line, and also the point at which the voltage is to be maximized, and whether your source is constant-voltage, constant-current, or constant-power.

Answer (score 0):

> *But how can I connect this idea to the input impedance?*

We're talking about steady-state sinusoidal AC impedances here (just to remind anyone reading) and, the relevant formula is this: -

[image]

The image above was taken from my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/318058/what-is-the-difference-between-characteristic-impedance-and-input-impedance-in-t/318063#318063). I would suggest that you open your favourite spreadsheet and make a graph of input impedance vs line length. I would also suggest that you research [quarter wave impedance transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-wave_impedance_transformer) because, the phenomena you are asking about is most prevalent when the cable length is a quarter wave long and, conveniently, the more complex formula (above) reduces to this: -

$$\dfrac{Z_{IN}}{Z_0}=\dfrac{Z_0}{Z_L}$$

> *How can I intuitively understand input impedance?*

Intuition is not a word that sits so easily with t-line theory. It can be a slog and, eventually it becomes intuitive.