# Finding the reflection coefficient for a wave incident from the left into the first transmission line?

Tags: lumped, reflection-coefficient

I am having a hard time dealing with lumped impedance in problems related to traveling waves.

How can I handle problems where both characteristic impedance and lumped impedance are present, as in the example below?

A series lumped inductor L is inserted into a transmission line section as shown in the picture. The characteristic impedance of the transmission line is Z_0. The line is terminated to the right so that there is no reflection off the end of the line.

[image: pic]

Is it correct to solve it as below?

[image: pic2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case as redrawn:

[image]

[image]

You think that line section A has load impedance Zin and that's right. Then you wrote the next calculation for the complex reflection factor at the right end of section A (judgement added):

[image]

You should see that Zo-Zo=0 and Zo+Zo=2Zo. I must admit that I do not have a slightest idea how you got the result =1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't understand enough, so I changed the content a bit and asked the question again. Please answer that question as well.

Comment: You haven't addressed these things: (1) *How can I find the reflection coefficient for a wave incident from the left into the first transmission line?* and (2) *How can I handle problems where both characteristic impedance and lumped impedance are present.*

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it correct to solve it as below?*

You have to calculate the left-side input impedance and, to do that, you have to know the length of the line to the point where it "hits" the inserted inductor. That inductor forms a load together with the characteristic impedance of the line on the right (both are series components).

You have to resolve this by considering the following formula taken from [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/318058/what-is-the-difference-between-characteristic-impedance-and-input-impedance-in-t): -

[image]

So, in your particular case, \$Z_L\$ is the impedance of the inductor in series with the characteristic impedance of the line to the right.

So, once you have the input impedance, you can work out the reflection coefficient (using your 2nd formula).

<sub>I have edited my answer to make it clearer to the OP</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I didn't understand enough, so I changed the content a bit and asked the question again. Please answer that question as well.

Comment: @FieldWave you have unaccepted my correct answer and accepted an "answer" that doesn't address the question you raised. You might wish to consider this strange action. Let me remind you that in your question above you asked for the reflection coefficient into the left-side transmission line and, I have given that answer. I have also correctly answered your latest question. Stack exchange is a site that showcases good questions and answers and, where there is a mismatch between question and accepted answer, there is a small site degradation.

Comment: My question is how to find the reflection coefficient. You claim that you also answered the method for calculating the reflection coefficient, but the focus was on modifying the method for calculating the input impedance, and the method for calculating the reflection coefficient that I suggested is correct as is, which is also a statement that you modified 1-2 hours ago. Take a good look again. The author of the answer I chose directly and kindly explained how to calculate the reflection coefficient. So it was adopted.

Comment: Also, there was something uncomfortable about the way you responded. But I never complained to you. I said thank you.

Comment: Also, if I adopt one answer, can't I adopt another answer? I chose the other answer because it was more suitable, so what's the problem? I don't want to waste my energy arguing about this. I don't understand why you keep saying this.

Comment: You have accepted an answer that does not address your question. That's the problem.

Comment: Stack Exchange is a great site and one I appreciate. Also, I am always grateful to everyone who responds.

Comment: You keep repeating the same thing over and over again. Look again at the answer you wrote before editing and the answer of the author I adopted.

Comment: I hope Stack Exchange continues to thrive. Because then I will be able to receive help and also be able to help others.

Comment: You asked (1) *How can I find the reflection coefficient for a wave incident from the left into the first transmission line?* and (2) *How can I handle problems where both characteristic impedance and lumped impedance are present*. These I addressed and, regarding your 3rd question (*Is it correct to solve it as below?*), I chose not to criticize your flawed math but directly address the two main points. I updated my answer because there were typos and a need to emphasize more clarity to you because you (by your own admission in comments) didn't *understand enough*.