# How can I deal with the traveling waves associated with lumped impedance?

Tags: lumped, reflection-coefficient

The answer I want to get is how to find the reflection coefficient.

I wanted to know how to find the reflection coefficient and so this is a different question as the question was written to get that.

I am having a hard time dealing with lumped impedance in problems related to traveling waves.

How can I handle problems where both characteristic impedance and lumped impedance are present, as in the example below?

Z0, Z2 are characteristic impedances and Z1 is lumped impedance. When a 100[v] DC incident wave enters, what is the reflection coefficient at the boundary between Z0 and Z1?

[image: pic]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i find the reflection coeeficient for a wave incident from the left into the first transmission line?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/690616/how-can-i-find-the-reflection-coeeficient-for-a-wave-incident-from-the-left-into)

Comment: You should do a simulation then see if you can handle with it.

Comment: @Hearth The answer I want to get is how to find the reflection coefficient.

Comment: @Hearth Someone wrote a response correcting part of the question rather than the answer the questioner was trying to get. So the questioner can no longer ask the questions he or she originally wanted to know?

Comment: @Hearth What I want to know from the beginning is how to deal with traveling waves when lumped impedance and characteristic impedance are present together (reflection coefficient and transmission coefficient are also included). The first question asked how to calculate the reflection coefficient. And I presented a hypothetical solution using my input impedance (Z_in) to find out how to solve the reflection coefficient.

Comment: @Hearth However, someone wrote an answer saying that the method for calculating the input impedance (Z_in) was wrong. So I said thank you. However, what I want to know is that the method of calculating the input impedance (Z_in) is wrong and not the correct method of calculating it, but rather how to calculate the reflection coefficient. So, without presenting my solution, I just asked a more direct question about the reflection coefficient.

Comment: @Antonio51 Is the question wrong? So, the reflection coefficient cannot be obtained? Or does inserting lumped impedance itself not work? If not, does that mean we should simulate it with a computer program?

Comment: No. The reflexion coefficient can be obtained and the simulation could help you to find it. I am on road. Inserting lumped impedance should also work, here in serie with the z2 line and so, z2 impedance.

Comment: @FieldWave my answer to your earlier question informed you how to calculate the input impedance to the line from the left. I then went on to say that the reflection coefficient was easily calculated from that and, given that you clearly demonstrated what the relevant formula for reflection coefficient was (in your question), there was no need to repeat that formula. You accepted my answer then de-accepted it and accepted an answer that did not answer the question you raised. Anyway, the question above is no different to your last question.

Comment: @Antonio51 Does this mean that we can treat characteristic impedance and lumped impedance like general circuit theory problem situations that deal with lumped impedance?
In other words, can a transmission line consisting of several both series and parallel, both lumped and characteristic impedances be calculated like the lumped impedance in general circuit theory?

Comment: The reflexion coefficient you want is equal to ((z1+z2)-z0)/((z1+z2)+z0). You should use laplace variable s to calculate z1 and calculate laplace value of coefficient. Then inverse laplace.

Comment: @Antonio51 Thank you very much for the clear answer. The reason I am repeating this question to Antonio's answer is because I do not understand that lumped impedance and characteristic impedance can be treated as the same thing from the perspective of a progressive wave.

Comment: @Antonio51 Is there a textbook or paper where I can find the answer to the question I am asking? This is because no matter how hard I search, I can't seem to find the content proving the justification for treating lumped impedance and characteristic impedance equally in any undergraduate books (cheng, griffiths, sadiku, hayt etc.)

Comment: @Antonio51 Or maybe it's self-evident and doesn't need to be proven, but I don't understand or I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: @Antonio51 There are two things that I find difficult to accept. First, when a traveling wave enters the junction of Z_0 and Z_1, the traveling wave does not know the existence of Z_2. But how does the reflected wave become a value that takes Z_2 into account? Of course, if the transmitted wave at the boundary of Z_0 and Z_1 is reflected at the boundary of Z_1 and Z_2, and the transmitted wave at the boundary of Z_0 and Z_1 is considered again, then this is true.

Comment: @Antonio51 The second thing that I find difficult to accept is considering lumped impedance like characteristic impedance. Isn't it clear that lumped impedance is related to the voltage drop at both ends of it and is different from characteristic impedance, which is the voltage wave at a point divided by the current wave?

Comment: The traveling wave "does" know the existence of z2 after z1 which is a "localized" impedance (the wave knows the characteristic impedance z2 ... length does not matter yet ...)

Comment: @Antonio51 Oh, I see. It's hard to accept, but that's the crucial point. Thank you so much.

Comment: I made an answer wth this point. i hope it is clear (?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the reflection coefficient at the boundary between Z0 and Z1?

Here is an example of what I mean ...
Note that there is a "coefficient emission" of 1/2=50/(50+50) at the beginning.

You can see that "vout" is "only" 100 ns displaced in time with "vout1".
See the curves "black" and "green" color.
At Vm and Vm1, see the "red" and "dotted black" curves.

This is for the **first** bouncing (here, there is only one, z1 and z2 are matched).

You must calculate Kr with Laplace and then take the inverse Laplace to get equations.
Note that there is a "transmitted" wave together with the reflected wave.
Boundary condition (at Vm) ... the voltage at the left (Wi+Wr) equal the voltage at the right (W12).

Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

[image]

Comment: I would like to sincerely thank you for awakening me to a time when I was stuck through the countless comments and thoughtful and kind replies.

Comment: @FieldWave No worries. It is a real pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

> *How can I handle problems where both characteristic impedance and
> lumped impedance are present, as in the example below?*

In your previous question you wrote this (that I believe applies in this question): -

> *The line is terminated to the right so that there is no reflection off
> the end of the line.*

If the line marked \$Z_2\$ is terminated in its characteristic impedance then, \$Z_2\$ will appear to be infinitely long and will present a constant impedance equal to its characteristic impedance.

<sub>I'm assuming that the transmission lines marked \$Z_0\$ and \$Z_2\$ are ideal and lossless of course</sub>

In short, \$Z_2\$ will behave like a \$\color{red}{\text{resistor}}\$.

You can then use \$Z_2\$'s characteristic impedance (a \$\color{red}{\text{resistor}}\$) in series with lumped impedance \$Z_1\$. Call it \$Z_3\$ for convenience: -

[image]

This forms the load to transmission line \$Z_0\$ and, you use \$Z_0\$'s characteristic impedance and \$Z_3\$ to calculate to reflection coefficient at the boundary of \$Z_0\$ and \$Z_3\$

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing mentioned of how long (=delay) the rightmost line has and of is there some load, too. I guess you want only a hint how to handle the case for the time period when there's no reflection arrived from the right end to the lumped impedance.

The incident wave which comes from the left branch to the lumped impedance is a 100 V step function. The reflection could be handled quite easily (see NOTE) if the lumped impedance was given in Laplace domain; for an inductor that is Z(s) = sL. You can consider the right line branch and the lumped impedance as a load which has Laplace domain impedance = Z(s) + Z2. Then you can apply the same reflection factor formula as you did in your previous question.

The Laplace domain reflection factor can be seen as a transfer function. The input is the incident wave and the reflected wave is the output. Multiply the Laplace transform of the input with the transfer function to get the Laplace transform of the output i,e, the reflected wave.

The inverse L-transform of the output is valid only as long as the reflection from the right end has not arrived to the lumped impedance. The reflected wave can be a tricky waveform, no matter the incident wave is a simple step. The reflection factor cannot be a single number except when the lumped impedance is a resistor.

Another approach is to go back to the basics and handle the case with differential equations. The lumped impedance also must be given as a differential equation between its voltage and current. Very likely you can finally formulate the reflection factor as a differential operator. That (Heaviside approach) is equivalent with the Laplace domain method. I skip it.

Hopefully you have about one year of (properly done) university level engineering math studies behind you to handle the things mentioned above.

If you have Zo, Z2 and the lumped impedance as numerical values you can check the result by performing a transient analysis in a circuit analysis program. There's still available Micro Cap (now freeware) which has transmission line as a component.

NOTE: It's easy only as a principle, the calculations can be massive.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. There are two things that I find difficult to accept. First, when a traveling wave enters the junction of Z_0 and Z_1, the traveling wave does not know the existence of Z_2. But how does the reflected wave become a value that takes Z_2 into account? Of course, if the transmitted wave at the boundary of Z_0 and Z_1 is reflected at the boundary of Z_1 and Z_2, and the transmitted wave at the boundary of Z_0 and Z_1 is considered again, then this is true.

Comment: The second thing that I find difficult to accept is considering lumped impedance like characteristic impedance. Isn't it clear that lumped impedance is related to the voltage drop at both ends of it and is different from characteristic impedance, which is the voltage wave at a point divided by the current wave?

Comment: If I think deeply again based on your answer, will I be able to resolve the two things that are difficult for me to accept?

Comment: I really appreciate your response. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A few transmission line fundamentals allow a straight forward algebraic approach for calculating the voltage reflection coefficient caused by the Z0 to Z1 junction.

1. Recall that an infinitely long transmission line will exhibit an input impedance equal to its Z<sub>O</sub> regardless of how it is, or is not, terminated.
2. Recall that the formula for a voltage reflection coefficient, Γ<sub>L</sub>, caused by a load, Z<sub>L</sub>, terminating a transmission line of a characteristic impedance, Z<sub>O</sub> is given as Γ<sub>L</sub> = (Z<sub>L</sub>-Z<sub>O</sub>)/(Z<sub>L</sub>+Z<sub>O</sub>). We should presume all values to be complex numbers.

By combining these basic fundamentals, we can find the solution. We treat Z2 as an infinitely long transmission line. This then simply manifests as itself as its characteristic impedance which is in series with Z1. We calculate Z<sub>L</sub> as Z1+Z2 and plug the this into the above formula. This will give you the voltage reflection coefficient caused by the Z0 to Z1 junction.

Keep in mind, however, that there may be an additional non-zero voltage reflection coefficient as a result of the termination, or lack thereof, of Z2. So your overall solution may require more consideration than simply the voltage reflection coefficient caused by Z1.

If this is a real world problem, the phase delays and losses of the respective transmission lines should also be factored into the solution.