# From the perspective of a progressive wave, what is lumped impedance?

Tags: characteristic-impedance, waveguide, lumped

This question asks about **the meaning of lumped impedance** in **traveling wave** theory.

Should lumped impedance be viewed as something like a point charge, a point mass, or a direct delta function?

[image: pic]

When a traveling wave enters the interface between Z_0 and Z_1, the traveling wave knows the characteristic impedance Z_2 behind the lumped impedance
Z_1.

1. How can a traveling wave know in advance the existence of Z_2?
2. How should lumped impedance be viewed in the analysis of traveling waves?

Is lumped impedance lengthless?

Even if it is a very short length, it will have a non-zero length.

If so, isn't it the same as characteristic impedance?

Therefore, the traveling wave cannot know in advance Z_2 behind Z_1, right?

Comment: What is inadequate about the answers you got the [first](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/690651/how-can-i-deal-with-the-traveling-waves-associated-with-lumped-impedance) [two](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/690616/finding-the-reflection-coefficient-for-a-wave-incident-from-the-left-into-the-fi) times you asked about this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is lumped impedance lengthless?*

Yes it is regarded as length-less. This means it doesn't behave like a transmission line. If its length is non zero then it wouldn't be a lumped impedance but, would be regarded as a transmission line.

But, the trick is knowing when to regard a real non-ideal component as an ideal lumped component and, not a transmission line.

> *Should lumped impedance be viewed as something like a point charge, a
> point mass, or a direct delta function?*

You regard it as an ideal component that has no transmission-line properties i.e. it has zero dimensions and cannot create reflections.

> *Even if it is a very short length, it will have a non-zero length*

You are confusing a lumped impedance with a non-ideal lumped impedance. With a non-ideal lumped impedance you may choose to regard it as a transmission line at higher frequencies.

> *How can a traveling wave know in advance the existence of Z_2?*

Because the lumped impedance introduces no transmission-line delays.

> *How should lumped impedance be viewed in the analysis of traveling
> waves?*

By definition, it must be regarded as a zero-dimensioned ideal component thus, introducing no transmission-line delays.